# How to populate a List that's within a class in C#?

Tags: c#, list, class

I'm trying to understand nested types, but even after checking several sites I still don't get it. I have a List that's in a class. I don't see how I can add new items to the List because when I try, it overwrites the existing items with my new ones. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Master master = new Master();
        master.Username = "Barry";

        Quiz quiz = new Quiz();
        quiz.QuizID = "quiz ID";
        master.quiz = quiz;

        Answers answers = new Answers();
        answers.Answer1 = "answer 1";
        answers.Answer2 = "answer 2";
        answers.Answer3 = "answer 3";
        master.quiz.answers.Add(answers);
        answers.Answer1 = "answer 11";
        answers.Answer2 = "answer 22";
        answers.Answer3 = "answer 33";
        master.quiz.answers.Add(answers);
    }
}

public class Answers
{
    public string Answer1 { get; set; }
    public string Answer2 { get; set; }
    public string Answer3 { get; set; }
}

public class Quiz
{
    public string QuizID { get; set; }
    public List<Answers> answers = new List<Answers>();
}

public class Master
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public Quiz quiz { get; set; }
}
```

When I do the second .Add and then check what's in `master.quiz.answers` it shows two entries, but they're both the 11, 22, 33 values as if the second .Add overwrote the data that was already in the list.

Thanks.

Comment: Move the declaration inside the loop to get a fresh object on each pass of the loop, currently you are assigning new values to the old values and overriding is happening, you need use new keyword on each new answer object with his own Answer1,2 & 3, by saying answer 1 = 10, answer 1 = 60, you will override old value (10) with new value (60).

Comment: Yes, because you add the *same* object to collection twice. Try to compare `master.quiz.answers[0] == master.quiz.answers[1]` and you'll see that it'll return `true` as both references point to the same object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to construct two distinct objects with the new operator.

i.e.

```
Answers answers = new Answers();
        answers.Answer1 = "answer 1";
        answers.Answer2 = "answer 2";
        answers.Answer3 = "answer 3";
        master.quiz.answers.Add(answers);

Answers anotherAnswer = new Answers(); // construct a new object here
        anotherAnswer.Answer1 = "answer 11";
        anotherAnswer.Answer2 = "answer 22";
        anotherAnswer.Answer3 = "answer 33";
        master.quiz.answers.Add(anotherAnswer);
```

As an aside, you can make this a little bit cleaner with object initializer syntax:

```
Answers answers = new Answers
{
      Answer1 = "answer 1",
      Answer2 = "answer 2",
      Answer3 = "answer 3"
};
master.quiz.answers.Add(answers);

Answers anotherAnswer = new Answers
{
      Answer1 = "answer 11",
      Answer2 = "answer 22",
      Answer3 = "answer 33"
}; 
master.quiz.answers.Add(anotherAnswer);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try instantiating the answer object again before adding it to the quiz for the second time.

`answers = new Answers();`

Answer (score 2):

Because you are updating  the same object.
use

```
 answers = new Answers();
```

after adding the object to the list